# Removing search term from Flask form

Tags: python, flask

I have a form to search for a user by email to delete them.  After deleting the user and returning to the page, the old search term is still in the form.  How do I remove the value from the form after submitting?

Using `request.form.clear()` or `request.form['email'] = ""` raises `TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' objects are immutable`.

```
if 'delete_user' in request.form:
# don't allow current user to delete themselves
    if user.id != current_user.id:
        User.delete(user)
        flash(user.username + " has been deleted", 'warning')
        user = None
        request.form.clear()

searchForm = SearchForm(request.form, obj=user)
return render_template("users/admin.html", user=user, form=searchForm)
```

Comment: Isn't `SearchForm` a WTForms object? This may have nothing to do with Flask itself. (I'm extremely skeptical it does, since Flask does *nothing* to generate response pages. Even the default install just uses Jinja2 for templating.) Also, there are some fairly big assumptions about what might be going on in the template itself here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it looks like the search field is *probably* filled using `form=searchForm`, which is being constructed via `SearchForm(request.form, obj=user)`. You need to adjust what you're passing into that constructor. Something like the below should work:

```
  formParams = {key: value for key, value in x.items() if key != "email"}

  searchForm = SearchForm(formParams, obj=user)

  return render_template("users/admin.html", user=user,
                                             form=searchForm)
```

Comment: Interesting, not what I did but obviously achieves the same result. I did `copyRequestForm = request.form.copy()`, set email to an empty string and used it here `searchForm = SearchForm(copyRequestForm, obj=user)`. Cheers!

Comment: I have a love affair with unnecessary dictionary comprehensions. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WTForms, you can do the validation in the form.  There's also no apparent reason to pass a user object to a form meant for *searching* for a user to delete.  Getting the user is the job of the form based on the input.  Also, assuming this is a POST request, you should redirect after a successful POST, not clear the form manually.

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import StringField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, ValidationError

class DeleteForm(Form):
    email = StringField(validators=[InputRequired()])

    def validate_email(self, field):
        self.user = # however you get the user, not shown in the original code

        if self.user.id == current_user.id:
            raise ValidationError("you can't delete yourself")

@app.route('/delete_by_email', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_by_email():
    form = DeleteForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('deleted {}'.format(form.user.username), 'warning')
        User.delete(form.user)
        # redirect back after a successful post
        # the new request will not have the form filled again
        return redirect('delete_by_email')

    # initial get or form didn't validate
    return render_template('delete_by_email.html', form=form)
```